# Cannot Ping Another Google Compute VM created with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

Need some help for Google Cloud Platform.  I created TWO GCE VM using terraform `google_compute_instance`.  The name of the VM is `instance-1` and `instance-2`.  I then create another TWO GCE VM using Google console by the name `instance-3` and `instance-4`.  For all the VMs, I can ping itself locally with their own hostname shortname and fqdn.  For terraform creation, I cannot ping `instance-1` using its shortname from `instance-2` but fqdn is working fine.  On the otherhand, for VMs I've created using Google Console, I can ping each other with shortname and vice-versa.

How can I achieve the same Google console creation behavior when creating VM using Terraform ?  What am I missing in Terraform that prevents the VM to be pingable with shortname.  How do I list the Google Internal DNS to check if VMs created are registered into Google Internal DNS

```
instance-2 $ ping instance-1  
ping: bad address 'instance-1'

instance-2 $ ping instance-1.asia-northeast1-a.c.myproject.internal  
PING instance-1 (10.100.0.33): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.100.0.33: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
64 bytes from 10.100.0.33: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
64 bytes from 10.100.0.33: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.099 ms
```

Comment: Go to the Google Cloud Console. What is `hostname`?

Comment: @John, I have found out the answer from google doc at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#setting-zonal-dns

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware of those settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#view_instance_dns_name) you can determine the Google Internal DNS name for an instance.

Comment: Thanks Mahboob.  I have found out the answer from google docs as well.  All I need is just to add metadata `VmDnsSetting=ZonalPreferred` to my project.  Is a bit strange that it doesn't need it when I create the instance from Console UI.  But anyway, it resolved my problem for now